# FOR /F is not working for Comma separated double quoted string in batch file

Tags: regex, windows, string, batch-file, split

I am having trouble splitting a line which contains double quoted strings separated by comma. String looks something like:

```
"DevLoc","/Root/Docs/srvr/temp test","171.118.108.22","/Results/data/Procesos Batch","C:\DataExport\ExportTool\Winsock Folder DB","C:\Export\ExportTool\Temp Folder","22"
```

Some strings values contain spaces. I want to store each double quoted string into a variable. Can anyone please help

Below is my batch script. variable 'EnvDetails' contains above line which need to be parsed.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 delims=," %%i in ("%EnvDetails%") do (
SET TEMPS=%%i
SET Path=%%j
SET host=%%k
SET scriptPath=%%l
SET WINSP_HOME=%%m
SET PUTTY_HOME=%%n
SET portNum=%%o
@echo %TEMPS% > temp.txt
@echo %MPath% >> temp.txt
@echo %host% >> temp.txt
@echo %scriptPath% >> temp.txt
@echo %WINSCP_HOME% >> temp.txt
@echo %PUTTY_HOME% >> temp.txt
@echo %portNum% >> temp.txt
)
```

Comment: the "EnvDetails" is the string that contains the other strings with quotes and commas?

Comment: yes.
EnvDetails = "DevLoc","/Root/Docs/srvr/temp test","171.118.108.22","/Results/data/Procesos Batch","C:\DataExport\ExportTool\Winsock Folder DB","C:\Export\ExportTool\Temp Folder","22"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're attempting to retrieve your variable values within the same parenthetical code block as they're set.  Because the cmd interpreter replaces variables with their values before the commands are executed, you're basically echoing empty values to temp.txt.  To wait until the variables have been defined before expanding them, you'd need delayed expansion.

But you're really making this more complicated than it needs to be.  What else are you doing with the variables, besides echoing them out to a text file?

What you should do instead is use a basic `for` loop rather than `for /f`.  `for` without any switches evaluates lines similar to CSV parsers anyway, splitting on commas, semicolons, unquoted spaces and tabs, and so forth.

Given that you're basically splitting a line on commas and echoing each token, in order, to a text file, one token per line, you can simplify your code quite a bit like this:

```js
@echo off
>temp.txt (
    for %%I in (%EnvDetails%) do echo %%~I
)
```

---

If I'm mistaken and you do indeed intend to perform further processing on the data; if you do actually need the variables, then this example demonstrates delayed expansion:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set EnvDetails="DevLoc","/Root/Docs/srvr/temp test","171.118.108.22","/Results/data/Procesos Batch","C:\DataExport\ExportTool\Winsock Folder DB","C:\Export\ExportTool\Temp Folder","22"

>temp.txt (
    FOR /F "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%i in ("%EnvDetails%") do (
        SET "TEMPS=%%~i"
        SET "MPath=%%~j"
        SET "host=%%~k"
        SET "scriptPath=%%~l"
        SET "WINSCP_HOME=%%~m"
        SET "PUTTY_HOME=%%~n"
        SET "portNum=%%~o"

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo !TEMPS!
        echo !MPath!
        echo !host!
        echo !scriptPath!
        echo !WINSCP_HOME!
        echo !PUTTY_HOME!
        echo !portNum!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Final note: The tilde notation of `%%~i`, `%%~j`, etc, strips surrounding quotation marks from each token.  If you intentionally wish to preserve the quotation marks as part of the variable values, remove the tildes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. basic FOR loop is echoing values correctly into text file. But I want to store each string in a variable and use them in other steps. How can I store each double quoted string into a separate variable?